# C# - Downloading a file from Amazon S3 bucket and catch error when it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, error-handling, async-await

I generate a list of filenames that I need to download from S3. Everything works fine but it breaks when it encounters a file that does not exist. When I try to list the contents of the bucket, I get an access denied error even though this should work fine, according to the vendor... so I gave up on trying to list contents.

Instead, is there a way I can just catch the error for the async method when it tries to download something that doesn't exist without it crashing my program? I'd like to just move onto the next file in the list if one fails.

The error I get when I try a file that doesn't exist:

```
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied --->   
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (403) 
Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse() --- 
End of inner exception stack trace
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace AlgoSeekDecompressor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<string>()
            {
                "Apple.csv",
                "Banana.csv",
                "Canteloupe.csv",
            };

            var downloadPath = @"E:\My_Folder";

            Task.Run(async () => { await DownloadFilesAsync(list, downloadPath); }).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Done downloading");
        }

        static async Task DownloadFilesAsync(List<string> list, string downloadPath)
        {
            var accessKey = "#################";
            var secretAccessKey = "#########################";

            var client = new AmazonS3Client(
                accessKey,
                secretAccessKey,
                RegionEndpoint.USEast1
            );

            foreach (var file in list)
            {
                var bucketName = "amazon_s3_bucket";

                //There is a prefix that is the first letter of the filename
                var filename = file.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + "/" + file + ".csv.gz";

                var request = new GetObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = filename,
                    RequestPayer = RequestPayer.Requester
                };

                if (!Directory.Exists(downloadPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory {0} does not exist - creating directory", downloadPath);
                }

                var filePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, filename);
                var appendToFile = false;

                using (var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                    await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(filePath, appendToFile, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A 403 error is when you don't have the right permissions for the file. A missing file would get you a 404.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there a way to just catch this and move onto the next file?

Comment: Are you asking how to _catch_ an `AmazonS3Exception`? Because that would probably involve some kind of `catch(AmazonS3Exception)` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to not use the `Task.Run` since there is no reason for using it you can just call your method directly.

About catching exceptions this would work:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    ///....

    var messages = await DownloadFilesAsync(list, downloadPath);

    if (!messages.Any())
      Console.WriteLine("Done");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("Some of files failed");
  }

  static async Task<List<string>> DownloadFilesAsync(List < string > list, string downloadPath) {
    //....

    var errorMessages = new List<string>();
    foreach(var file in list) {
      //.....

      var filePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, filename);
      var appendToFile = false;

      using GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request);

      try {

        await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(filePath, appendToFile, CancellationToken.None);

        if(response.HttpStatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            errorMessages.Add($"Failed to download {objectName} with status {response.HttpStatusCode}");

      } 
     catch (AmazonS3Exception ex) {

        errorMessages.Add($"Error saving {objectName}: {ex.Message}");
      }

     catch (Exception ex) {

        errorMessages.Add($"Unhandled exception on saving {objectName}: {ex.Message}");
      }
    }

    return errorMessages;
  }
```

Comment: This does not address *I'd like to just move onto the next file in the list if one fails.*

Comment: Thanks for the help but this does not compile because it says I must run this in an async method. When I try to run it using a Task, it still breaks on a bad file.

Comment: @eek I forgot to make ``Main`` method as async. answer updated